# How can I resume execution of a function (not start it again) using swapcontext()?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, scheduler, context-switch

I am building a pre-emptive userspace thread scheduler which uses a timer to interrupt threads and switch between them according to priority. However, once a thread is interrupted, I cannot seem to let it finish; only start it again. Is what I am asking for even possible using swapcontext? The result of this code, which should allow itake5seconds() to complete, just loops the "Hello" message over and over.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

static ucontext_t mainc, newthread;

void itake5seconds()
{
    puts("Hello. I take 5 seconds to run.");
    sleep(5);
    puts("And I'm done! Wasn't that nice?");
}

void timer_handler(int signum)
{
    puts("Doing some scheduler stuff.");
    swapcontext(&mainc, &newthread);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

    getcontext(&newthread);
    newthread.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(5000);
    newthread.uc_stack.ss_size = 5000;
    newthread.uc_link = &mainc;
    makecontext(&newthread, &itake5seconds, 0);

    struct itimerval timer;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 500000;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 500000;

    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling an "unsafe" function in the signal handler (`swapcontext`). Therefor, the behavior of your program is "undefined".

From [man 7 signal](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal):

> A signal handler function must be very careful, since processing elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution of the program. POSIX has the concept of "safe function". If a signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.

See the "Example for SVID Context Handling" section in [Complete Context Control](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_node/libc_454.html#SEC464) for an example of how you can work this with a signal handler. But basically you'd use a `volatile int` global variable to flag that your signal handler was called and instead do the `swapcontext` call from normal code (i.e. code that's not running from within the context of signal handling).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not saving the current execution context that swapcontext() returns to its first parameter.

Comment: Can you provide the updated code for everyone to see?